# Specifying a token to Ansible lookup

Tags: ansible, consul

I need to issue a lookup against Consul's key/value. I tried passing the token this way but I'm still getting an access denied. The token is definitely correct.

```
{{ lookup('consul_kv',item,"token=mysecretoken") }}
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried this syntax:

```
- debug: msg='key contains {{item}}'
  with_consul_kv:
    - 'key/to/lookup_one token={{acl_token}}'
```

Comment: also see examples here: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/test/integration/roles/test_consul_kv/tasks/main.yml#L70